# When do we need memory_limit greater than post_max_size in PHP ini

Tags: php, wordpress

I had an issue with the wordpress bacip plugin to compress the files and folders which had the names which were not utf8 encoded, where in we ended up with an observation that the post_max_size was greater than memory_limit, the solution provider says it is the reason for failure in compression..

Please help me understand the reason behind this, if it is so..

Comment: `memory_limit` exceeds only when server sends too much long data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

post_max_size is the limit of post when you receive a post request for example 50mb of post and stored in a global variable as $_POST['message'] and you only have memory_limit of 32mb it will error it's because you can only allocate a total of 32mb per process. In this case you are using 50mb+ in single request.

real example if int have a size of 4 byte and you have an array of ints which lenght is 8 you are consuming 32byte in memory_limit

```
<?php
$intArray = range(1, 8); // array(1, 2, 3, ..., 8) consumes 32bytes
$_POST['message'] = range(1, 8); // consumes 32bytes also
```

Answer (score 1):

If your input is larger than your space to store it, than PHP will throw a fatal error.

It's akin to someone handing you a textbook and telling you to copy its contents on to a small piece of paper. You don't have enough room; you have to give up.